# Shortening list objects to only digits and creating new list in Python

Tags: python, list, for-loop

I have a list which has a few hundred dates in it but I need to filter out only the time in the format hhmmss (no : in between so I can turn them into int later on).

The list I have so far looks like this:

```
list_dates = ['Fri Nov 30 15:56:43 +0000 2018', 'Fri Nov 30 15:56:44 +0000 2018', 'Fri Nov 30 15:56:45 +0000 2018', 'Fri Nov 30 15:56:46 +0000 2018', ... ]
```

My approach so far is:

```
raw_list = []
new_list = []

def ConversionStrings():

    j = 0
    while j < (len(list_dates)+1):

        for j in list_dates:

            raw_list.append((list_dates[j])[11:19])
            j += 1

    i = 0
    while i < len(raw_list):

        for i in raw_list:
            item = (raw_list[i]).replace(":", "")
            new_list.append(item)
            i += 1
```

Obviously this doesn't work but I can't figure out what I am doing wrong as I am pretty new to Python. The error I get is this and its referring to the j in the for loop

```
 TypeError: list indices must be integers or slices, not str
```

How can I change my code to get this output? Or is there maybe a simpler way to solve this problem?

```
 >>> new_list = [155643, 155644, 155645, ... ]
```

Answer (score 2):

Your issue is with this section of the code:

```
j = 0
while j < (len(list_dates)+1):

    for j in list_dates:

        raw_list.append((list_dates[j])[11:19])
        j += 1
```

Each `j` in `list_dates` is an element of the array, not the index of a certain element. So, when you try to get the `j`th element of `list_dates` with `list_dates[j]`, you're passing in a `str` as an index to the array, which doesn't make sense. You should just use another while loop like you did in the outer loop, or use `for k in range(len(list_dates))` or something similar.

Answer (score 2):

Instead of obscure

```
j = 0
while j < (len(list_dates)+1):

    for j in list_dates:

        raw_list.append((list_dates[j])[11:19])
        j += 1
```

use Pythonic (simpler, more readable, and more safe way)

```
for item in list_dates:
    raw_list.append(item[11:19])
```

and the same for

```
i = 0
while i < len(raw_list):

    for i in raw_list:
        item = (raw_list[i]).replace(":", "")
        new_list.append(item)
        i += 1
```

i. e. replace it with

```
for item in raw_list:
    item = item.replace(":", "")
    new_list.append(item)
```

Answer (score 1):

You could use a [list comprehension](https://docs.python.org/3/tutorial/datastructures.html#list-comprehensions):

```
list_dates = ['Fri Nov 30 15:56:43 +0000 2018', 'Fri Nov 30 15:56:44 +0000 2018', 'Fri Nov 30 15:56:45 +0000 2018', 'Fri Nov 30 15:56:46 +0000 2018']
result = [''.join(c for c in date.split()[3] if c.isnumeric())  for date in list_dates]
print(result)
```

**Output**

```
['155643', '155644', '155645', '155646']
```

If you want the result as integers, use [int](https://docs.python.org/3/library/functions.html#int):

```
result = [int(''.join(c for c in date.split()[3] if c.isnumeric())) for date in list_dates]
print(result)
```

**Output**

```
[155643, 155644, 155645, 155646]
```

Answer (score 0):

using `datetime` module you can do something like this. Link for further reading https://docs.python.org/2/library/datetime.html#strftime-strptime-behavior

```
from datetime import datetime
[datetime.strftime(datetime.strptime(i,'%a %b %d %H:%M:%S +0000 %Y'),'%H%M%S') for i in list_dates]
```

Output:

```
['155643', '155644', '155645', '155646']
```

In case you need to convert the values in int then cast them in the list comprehension itself to get the list of int values